# dot operator order of evaluation in c++

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence

I am reading "C++ Primer (5th Edition)" and I've run in something I'm not sure I understand correctly.

The example is pretty much similar to one they gave in the book. Imagine we have some function that returns string (or any class that has non-static members):

```
string some_function(par1, par2) {
     string str;
     // some code
     return str;
}
```

I know that you can use the return value of any function to access its members, i.e. something like this is valid:

```
auto size = some_function(arg1, arg2).size(); // or whatever member of class
```

However, since the dot operator `.` and function call operator `()` have left to right grouping and same precedence, the above expression should be something like this:

```
(some_function(arg1, arg2)).size()
```

I suppose I am right so far? The thing I don't understand here is order of evaluation. Since order of evaluation is not specified for `.` operator, it means that either `some_function(arg1, arg2)` or `size()` will be evaluated first. But how can it evaluate `size()` first if it doesn't know on which object is it working on? This implies that order of evaluation should be fixed from left to right, but it is not. How is this possible?

Another example is something like this:

```
 cin.get().get();
```

Again, it seems like first `cin.get()` should be evaluated before second `get()` since it won't know on which object is it working, but this doesn't seem to be necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators of the same precedence are evaluated according to their associativity, which you correctly observe is left-to-right for the operator group containing the function call and element selection operators.  Therefore, yes, given the expression

```
x = foo().bar();
```

The order of operations is

```
x = (((foo()).bar)());
```

accounting for relative precedence and associativity of all operators involved.  No one writes code in that manner, though.

Likewise, given

```
cin.get().get()
```

the order of operations is

```
(((cin.get)()).get)()
```

, so yes, the precedence rules result in the `cin.get()` sub-expression being evaluated first, yielding the object to which the second `.` (and thence the rest of the expression) is applied.

Comment: OK, maybe I am not getting this right, but shouldn't precedence and associativity just say how the operands of the operator are grouped? The order of evaluation could be different though, for example: a * b + c = (a * b) + c can be evaluated by first evaluating a, then b, multiplying them, and then evaluating c and adding it to result of a and b, or it can evaluate c and then b and a, or anything in between. So how does it work with dot operator? For example cin.get().get() <- it can evaluate second get first and cin later? How can it evaluate second get() without knowing the object?

Comment: @Murdac: `get` and `get()` are two distinct things: the first is just used to determine what method to use, the second is its application.  So as far as the dot operator is concerned, the two bits are the object & what method to use; once the dot is evaluated, you have a callable (that particular object's method) which can then be executed.

Comment: @Scott Hunter: I think I got it, I was actually misinterpreting the meaning of operator. It actually means "fetch me the member named foo from object to the left" which means it evaluates either the object first or the name of member first, which in the end allows for the given constructions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It was an interesting question, one you look at and first think its obvious, but then realize it is pretty subtle.

Comment: Yes, I had to think about my answer a bit.  The issue revolves around the question of what the operands are for each operator.  I had hoped that the grouping parentheses in my answer would clear up that aspect of the issue, but I guess they weren't sufficient.  Thanks for the assist @ScottHunter.

Comment: Also, yes, associativity *directly* governs how operands are grouped, which is not the same as order of evaluation.  (Good observation.)  An operator's operands must all be evaluated before the operator can be applied, however, so grouping has a strong effect on order of operations.  So strong, in fact, that for operators all of the same precedence, associativity does completely dictate the order of operations.

Comment: @Mudrac I am reading that book and come across the same confusion. But I still don't understand after reading you guy's comments. Would you like to explain it in more detail?